# How do I set a web part I uploaded so that it needs to be requested before deploying to a site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, app-catalog

so I'm an admin at my company's sharepoint. A week ago I uploaded a web part for a dev site that I have, installing went smoothly, and it runs on my site. However, I've received a report that the web part that I uploaded can still be seen and deployed by other users in their site. How do I configure my web part so that when end users want to install it to their site, they need a SPAdmin approval? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deploy an app in the tenant app catalog, then it will be available to all SharePoint sites.

If you want to have the app available in specific sites only, you need to deploy it to the site collection app catalog.

The setup for this is more complex, but it is documented here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog

> Previously, all add-ins and SharePoint Framework solutions had to be
> managed centrally in the tenant app catalog. While tenant
> administrators could delegate the access to other people in the
> organization, a deployed package was visible on all site collections.
> SharePoint offered no supported way of deploying add-ins and
> SharePoint Framework solutions only to specific sites.
>
> With the introduction of site collection app catalogs, tenant
> administrators can enable app catalog on the specific sites. Once
> enabled, site collection administrators can deploy SharePoint add-ins
> and SharePoint Framework solutions that will be available only in that
> particular site collection.

Comment: Although the proposed solution doesn't specifically solve my problem, at least with this method I'm able to control the deployment per site, so that the web part I uploaded can just be applied to the sites that I want. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, there is no OOB solution to meet your requirement.

You can only set a permission level to a sepcific user/group to stipulate whether a user/group can add/remove all web parts in a site coolection.

However, setting permission level to a specific web part is impossible currently in SharePoint Online.

Comment: did you test the site collection app catalog deployment?